# useState initial state is undefined (TypeError: setNav is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const {nav, setNav} = useState(true);
const changeState = () => {
    setNav(false)
};

useEffect(() => {
    changeState();
}, [nav]);
```

In this code snippet, I am setting the initial state as "true" and changing it to "false". No matter what state I set or change it throws a TypeScript error (undefined):

[image: error]

Comment: `useState()` returns an array, not an object, so destructuring it in object will initialize both variables as `undefined`.  Hence `const [nav, setNav] = useState(true);` is a correct way to destructure

Comment: It's [in the React documentation on hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`useState` returns an **array** with two elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), not an object:

```
const [nav, setNav] = useState(true);
//    ^           ^
```

React couldn't possibly know how you want to name your state, so it can't return an object with these properties.

Comment: thanks, I am really amazed as to how I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace const `{nav, setNav} = useState(true);`
by:

```
const [nav, setNav] = useState(true);
```

As `useState` returns an array